# Solving $\,f'(x)=[f(x)]^2$.

Tags: calculus

When differentiating $\ln(\frac{1}{1-x})$ I got $\frac{1}{1-x}$, and wondered how often this happened.

Taking

(1) $f(x) = \ln g(x)$ and

(2) $f ' (x) =g(x)$

I differentiated (1) to get (3) $f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$

Equating (2) and (3) resulted in $[g(x)]^2 = g'(x)$

I wondered if this was a known differential equation but couldn't find an example of it online. Are there any plausible next steps to find a form for $g(x)$?

Comment: I mean, it doesn't necessarily need a name: it can be solved by separation of variables when the value at the starting time is $\ne 0$, and for $g(t_0)=0$ you the constant $0$ is the only solution by Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem.

Comment: You can eyeball the solution $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ by just considering how the derivative of $x^{-1} = -x^{-2}$ and flipping the negative.

Comment: $f'/f^2=(-1/f)'.$

Comment: The Solution to the given ODE is $g(x)=-1/(x+a)$ , with constant $a$ , which in your case was $a=-1$ , hence $f(x)=\log(g(x))=\log(1/(-a-x))$ is the Scenario where your observation is generalized.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason separation of variables didn't stand out to me but following that approach I was able to get the general solution. Thanks,

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111066/are-there-any-techniques-for-solving-a-differential-equation-of-the-form-f-x/111096#111096 You can use this method to find two solutions of this equation as well.